# ODBC Oracle Connection error from MS Access

Tags: oracle, ms-access, odbc, tns

I currently support an MS Access database that has linked connections using the Microsoft ODBC Driver for Oracle.  I can connect to the current linked tables without any issues, but we are required for security reasons to change the password on the account accessing the Server.

I have changed the password successfully but now when I attempt to relink the tables I get the error:

```
ODBC--call failed
Microsoft ODBC driver for ORacle ORA-12154: TNS could not resolve service name
```

These tables are part of a critical application and now we can't connect.  Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ORA-12154 error indicates that you are specifying a TNS alias that is not resolving.  Are you using a DSN for your connection to Oracle?  If so, what is the TNS alias you're specifying there?  Does that alias exist in your tnsnames.ora file?  Are there multiple tnsnames.ora files on the client?

The tnsnames.ora file is on the client machine where Access is installed.  Without knowing what version of the Oracle client is installed, the simplest way to find out which tnsnames.ora file is being used is probably to open up a DOS prompt and type "tnsping `service_name`" where `service_name" is whatever TNS alias is specified in your DSN.  You'll get something like

```
C:\Users\jcave>tnsping fuddy_duddy

TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 07-OCT-2
010 08:10:51

Copyright (c) 1997, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
C:\oracle\product\11.1.0\db_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\sqlnet.ora

TNS-03505: Failed to resolve name
```

The "Used parameter files" line tells you the directory where the TNS related files are stored.  There should be a tnsnames.ora and a sqlnet.ora file in that directory.

Comment: Can you tell me where I would find the tnsnames.ora files?  Because I don't have access to the server except through this ODBC connection.

Comment: Strange thing is that I cannot connect using the 'Microsoft ODBC for Oracle' driver but I can connect with the 'Oracle in orant' driver.  See any issues in using that with Access?

Comment: Using the Oracle driver is generally the preferred approach.  The Microsoft ODBC driver for Oracle is obsolete-- it was never updated to stop using the Oracle 7 call interface API which has been depricated for more than a decade.